# How to replace 1 for true in jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have an object which gets passed to a function as such:

```
function(config['options'])
```

There are certain values in here such as `config['options']['property1']` which are set as 1, which I want to change to `true` (like wise 0 to `false`) before they get passed to this function.

How do I go about doing this, I can't seem to figure it using `.each()`

Comment: Question that hits me instantly is: "Is `config` a jQuery object or a 'normal' JavaScript object?"

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes whats the difference?

Comment: @Blowsie `.each()` only works on jQuery objects

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes thats not true. http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/dxQww/

Comment: @Blowsie and how is `$` not a jQuery object?
To elaborate:
`config.each(...)` won't work while `$(config).each(...)` will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`options` is an object, so use a for-in loop to iterate the properties:

```
for (var key in config.options) {
    var current = config.options[key];

    if (current === 1) {
        config.options[key] = true;
    }

    if (current === 0) {
        config.options[key] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `config.options[key] = config.options[key] === 1;`

Comment: @asawyer that will set any options that are not numeric `1` to `false`, which is most likely not what the OP desires.

Comment: Ah I see your point, the question was not clear if it only contains 1/0's or other values. +1's all around.

Comment: +1 for asawyer, nice idea.
If he just use the value to test if it's true or false, why change ?
test if(value) or if(!value) is the same, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `double negation` to convert the values into boolean. `!!1` becomes `true` and `!!0` becomes `false`

Answer (score 0):

This one works with the double negation:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: '1',
    prop3: 0,
    prop4: '0',
    prop5: true,
    prop6: false,
    prop7: 'test'
}, prop, val;

for(prop in obj) {
    val = Number(obj[prop]);

    !isNaN(val) && (obj[prop] = !!val);
}
```

Results in (JSON stringified):

```
{
    "prop1": true,
    "prop2": true,
    "prop3": false,
    "prop4": false,
    "prop5": true,
    "prop6": false,
    "prop7": "test"
}
```